# How to fix Document mode restart in IE 9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-9, doctype

I have a problem with opening my website in IE9. When I try to open my site I get this error in dev tools:

```
HTML1113: Document mode restart from Quirks to IE9 Standards
```

I googled and found an answer that suggested to use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE9" />
```

...but these do not work and I get the following message this time:

```
HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=Edge') ignored because document mode is already finalized.
```

What is my problem? I read several articles like [IE’s Compatibility Features for Site Developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx?Redirected=true) by Microsoft and traced my site with [Determining IE9’s Document Mode](http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/misc/How%20IE9%20Determines%20Document%20Mode.svg) flowchart and use all suggestions relating to **!doctype** on these sites but no-one could solve my problem and my IE engine reset after the page opened.

I develop my site with ASP.NET 4 on Windows Server 2008.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Without your website it's useless to speculate. Please link to your website and edit in the HTML of your page (excluding the `<body>`).

Comment: I have upload it for test [here](http://62.193.15.156:155/). Use username: "test@afe.tt" and password:"123456" to sign in and check this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One solution that should always work is to put your `X-UA-Compatible` in HTTP headers. Also, your `<!DOCTYPE>` should be specified at the top of your HTML document (`<!DOCTYPE html>` is the easiest one).

If you put your `X-UA-Compatible` declaration inside the `meta` tag you can run into the following problems:

1. [`X-UA-Compatible` is ignored unless it's present inside the first 4k of you page.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/18/optimal-html-head-ordering-to-avoid-parser-restarts-redownloads-and-improve-performance.aspx) If you put it somewhere in the bottom of your `head` section (or in the `body`) move it to top. The best place for it is right after encoding and language declarations.
2. `X-UA-Compatible` is ignored if it's put inside IE conditional comments. For example:

   ```
   <!--[if IE]>
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   <![endif]-->
   ```

   In this case you should remove conditional comments.
3. Also, you shouldn't have any text before the `doctype` declaration. [If you've got any HTML comments there, for example, the IE will switch to quirks mode.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/community/history/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?id=26)
4. Finally, check if you're viewing this site from the intranet. By default Compatibility View is enabled for Intranet sites.

I suggest set `X-UA-Compatible` header for you page and then see if your site is still switching to quirks mode. In that case you should check your markup and try to fix any [HTML validator errors](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) until it's back to Standards Mode.

Comment: Adding this to headers saved my day.. IE throws this also on every redirect, like 302. There's no HTML there, so it thinks it's quirks mode, duh. So STUPID...

Comment: In my case I was missing 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
at the beginning of the page. I just had <html>

Comment: RE: #2, It's possible to put `x-ua-compatibile` inside conditionals with a little hack http://målform.no/blog/x-ua-optimal. Without the hack, `x-ua-compatible` won't work inside a conditional, as you said, and it also won't work if there are conditionals before it http://målform.no/blog/html5-boiler-plate-prevents-x-ua-compatible. RE: #3, Conditional comments are OK before the doctype http://målform.no/blog/no-condition-comments. These aren't my articles, but my testing supports them.

Comment: @Andrew Андрей Листочкин i have no idea why i cant put any comments before `<!DOCTYPE html>` but when i changed the position of my html comment, it worked like charm. Thanks for solution.