# Emulate IE7 Before Document Finalizes

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have an iframe in which I'm trying to render each element under IE7 standards.

I have the meta tag set to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

with no specified DOCTYPE inisde the iframe's document, however it gets overridden by the surrounding document's IE9 standards as seen here

```
X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=EmulateIE7') ignored because document mode is already finalized.
```

Is there any way to achieve these standards within the iframe only before IE9 standards take over?

Answer (score 0):

IE ignores the X-UA-Compatible meta tag unless it's in the first 4k of your page.
So try to move it at the top of your head declaration.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095319/how-to-fix-document-mode-restart-in-ie-9)

**UPDATE**

Starting from IE9 you can't have different document modes on one page. Means you have to render the whole page in IE7 mode if the iframe requires that.

Comment: Within the iframe it's the very first <head> declaration; are you saying that placing "X-UA-Compatible" in the head tag of the global page will allow me to emulate older standards further down?

Comment: @ClayBanks Exactly, the browser is only rendered once at the beginning (with the options/properties at the very top) and all further declarations are being ignored.

Comment: Thanks @enyce12, the surrounding page is set to x-ua-compatible - IE=edge. This is appropriate because if it was set any lower the look and functionality would be dramatically altered. In short, the two (the global page and the iframe) need to work together while being set to different standards.

Comment: @ClayBanks Unfortunately you can't have different standard modes on one page. Means you have to render the whole page in IE7 mode if the iframe requires that...

Comment: Starting from IE9, [using multiple document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not possible.