# intranet jsf application opening in compatibility mode in IE9

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

i have made a intranet website in jsf, primefaces. becuase of IE 9 defaults it opens in compatability view.
i know i am supposed to use the tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

but it doesnt work instead it shows

> HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=edge') ignored because
>   document mode is already finalized.

i have used the tag as such

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Wan</title>



</h:head>
```

this is what it shows in the developers tools

```
<head>
<TITLE>Wan</TITLE><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/Wan/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-redmond"><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/Wan/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/Wan/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/Wan/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/Wan/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/Wan/javax.faces.resource/charts/charts.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/Wan/javax.faces.resource/charts/charts.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1"></SCRIPT>

<STYLE id=ex_canvas_>canvas {
    TEXT-ALIGN: left; WIDTH: 300px; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 150px; OVERFLOW: hidden
}
</STYLE>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/Wan/javax.faces.resource/wanstyle.css.jsf?ln=css">
<META content=IE=edge http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible>
```

i am guessing this is happening beacuse as mentioned in alot of other posts the meta tag has to be at the top of the head but i dont know how i could achive this.

**how do i make my meta tag to be the first tag in my application**

this is completely what the console in IE is showing

```
HTML1202: http://10.164.210.37:8080/Wan/welcome.jsf is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked. 
welcome.jsf
HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=edge') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 
welcome.jsf
S15: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Document mode restart in IE 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095319/how-to-fix-document-mode-restart-in-ie-9)

Comment: @Jens i have read the other question earlier and understand what the answer there is trying to say but i am unsure how i could apply it to my code. read my last line

Comment: I think that means there is a problem in your html code that requires the compatibility model. So you should find out what it is and fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jsf PrimeFaces you have to use the following to reorder the tags

```
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  </f:facet>
```

It moved the meta to the top of the generated header using that code and it worked

from the following [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/resource-ordering-in-primefaces/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a servlet filter to solve it

Add this to your *web.xml*

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>EdgeFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.my.package.filter.EdgeFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EdgeFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Java code:

```
public class EdgeFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        if (((HttpServletRequest) req).getRequestURI().endsWith(".js.jsf")
                || ((HttpServletRequest) req).getRequestURI().endsWith(".css.jsf")) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge"); // No more Compatibility Mode
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks alot for the reply but i found a much simpler solution which i have submitted as an answer

Comment: This solution is better because you do not need to add a meta tag to every page

Comment: @Jeef: most jsf applications will use templates. In that case you only do it once, in the template